# SSH tunnel to remote site

Tags: ssh, debian, webserver, ssh-tunnel

I have three servers, one with white IP (SERVER1) and another(SERVER2 192.168.1.50) in my local net connect to Internet through provider net like 10.10.*.*. Also in my local net I've my another mini-server (SERVER3 192.168.1.51). I cannot work with SERVER3 with ssh.

So, I want: run in SERVER2 command "curl http://localhost/json:3333" and get answer from SERVER3 like in my home net: http://192.168.1.51/json.

For that:
In SERVER2, I open ssh tunnel with command: 
"ssh -N -R 3333:192.168.1.51:80 admin@SERVER1"

And I have tunnel now in SERVER1, I send 'curl http://localhost:3333' and have right answer from http://192.168.1.51/index.html, but if I want to get any page I got fail, for sample: http://localhost/json:3333' will return 'Apache/2.4.25 (Debian) Server at localhost Port 80'

How I can tunneling all SERVER3 site with path and pages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple mistake, right command must be http://localhost:3333/json'